# Trying to use angular 1.5 variable inside blade template engine

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using angular 1.5 and laravel 5.3, I have a controller which holds a questions array, and I also passing this array to the view.
What I'm trying to do is:

```
<div ng-if="questions.length > 0">
            <md-card ng-repeat="question in questions">
                <md-card-content>
                    <h4><% question.title %></h4>
                    <p ng-bind-html="renderHtml(question.content)"></p>
                    <p>{{ $questions['<% question.id %>']->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
                </md-card-content>
            </md-card>
        </div>
```

But its like the blade engine can't get the value of <% question.id %>.
By the way, I changed angular from {{}} to <%%>.
Thanks

Comment: How do you expect this to work? Blade is compiled on server side. Before Angular compiles it on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

**QuestionsController:**

```
$questionsForAngular = [];

foreach($questions as $question) {
    $questionsForAngular[] = $question->created_at->diffForHumans();
}
```

**angular controller:**

```
$scope.setQuestions = function(questions) {
    $scope.questionsFromBackend = questions;
}
```

**angular view:**

```
<div ng-if="questions.length > 0" ng-init='setQuestions({{ $questionsForAngular }})'>
    <md-card ng-repeat="question in questions">
        <md-card-content>
            <h4><% question.title %></h4>
                <p ng-bind-html="renderHtml(question.content)"></p>
                <p><% questionsFromBackend %></p>
        </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
</div>
```

Your solution doesn't work because blade template is rendered before angulars.